# Check folder to see if new song already recorded

Tags: batch-file

Main music folder called WORLD has list of songs. I get a list of NEW_MUSIC to add to WORLD folder. Sometimes the New songs will have extra characters ie __1 or _1 etc added to their title so I would like to be able to enter part of each NEWMUSIC song as a variable and check to see if is has already been entered with a variation of title. I need to see list of all songs in WORLD folder starting with the variable I entered from seeing NEWMUSIC folder name. Below  are samples of the two files used. I have played around with BAT files a little but I'm stuck trying to get a list of similar songs.

### NEWMUSIC folder

```
Name                                Ext

ROOTS.RAGGA_1                       mp3
SAGINOU_1                           mp3
SAMBA.TI,.SAMBA.EU                  mp3
```

### WORLD folder

```
Name                                Ext

ROOTS.RAGGA                         mp3
SAGINOU_1                           mp3
SALPICA                             mp3
```

Work folder has 2 of the 3 songs. 1 has same spelling and 1 has extra characters _1

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts by providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also take the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this:

In my testing environment I have two folders - `NEWMUSIC` AND `WORLD`.

Their contents are as follows:

```
NEWMUSIC -
    Roots.Ragga_1.txt
    Saginou_1.txt
    Samba.TI.txt

WORLD - 
    Roots.Ragga.txt
    Saginou_1.txt
    Salpica.txt
```

This is the code I've used for my particular situation:
`for /f "delims=_" %%i in ('dir newmusic /b') do echo %%i & dir world /b | find /i /c "%%~ni"`

It returns:

```
Roots.Ragga
1
Saginou
1
Samba.TI.txt
0
```

How it works:

It iterates through the files in NEWMUSIC and searched for them (filename only) in WORLD and returns the matches. As you can see by the output, it cuts off anything in the filename after a '_'. You can change this as you see fit via the `"delims=_"` portion of the `FOR` command.

This will more than likely not be a perfect solution, however it is easily adjusted to suit.